# Transform a pdf from position and velocity to position and time

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a problem where I have an object's PDF in position and velocity and I need it in position and time.

(It would be sufficient to just find $p(x | t)$, where $x$ is position and $t$ is time).

The distribution is normal, so let $\mathbf{x} \sim N(\mathbf{\mu}, \Sigma)$ where $\mathbf{x} = [x, v]^T$.  Knowing $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ I already know $p(x, v)$, and it's pretty trivial to get $p(x | v)$.

I want to assert that $t = -\frac{x}{v}$ and find $p(x, t)$ -- but I'm hitting a wall finding that, or $p(x | t)$.

Comment: $t=x/v$ won’t make any sense as a time value if one of $x$ or $v$ is negative (which is allowed with non-zero probability if they are normally distributed)...

Comment: Actually I had the sign of $t$ wrong -- I'm looking for collisions, and my physical problem imposes a precondition that $x$ and $v$ have opposite signs.  But mathematically, there's not a problem with $t < 0$ -- it just means that the collision happened in the past.